# Component not accessible from route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, ember-cli

My ember app uses a pod structure so that I have a structure similar to:

```
├───pods
│   ├───application
│   ├───components
│   │   └───modal-picker
│   ├───login
│   ├───profile
│   │   ├───energy
│   │   │   └───source
│   │   ├───food
│   │   ├───transport
│   │   ├───travel
│   │   └───user
│   └───register
```

I have a component **modal-picker** component that I want to inject into the **profile/transport** template as follows:

```
  <form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'showPicker' 'modal-picker'}}><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Car</button>
    {{outlet 'modal-picker'}}
  </form>
```

The **showPicker** action triggers the display of said picker via an action configured in the route:

```
showPicker: (name, model)->
       @render('modal-picker', Ember.Object.create().reopen
         outlet: 'modal-picker'
       )
```

here's the code in the component

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

ModalPickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend

  actions:
    show: (->
      @.$('.modal').modal().on 'hidden.bs.modal', =>
        @sendAction 'action', vehicule
    ).on('didInsertElement')

    pick: (vehicule)->
      @.$('.modal').modal('hide')
      @sendAction 'action', vehicule

`export default ModalPickerComponent`
```

When I click on the **showPicker** button I get the following error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Could not find "modal-picker" template or view.
```

I tried doing an import of the component by adding the following line to my **ProfileTransportRoute**

```
`import ModalPickerComponent from 'components/modal-picker'`
```

But then I get the following error:

```
 Could not find module `components/modal-picker` imported from `impact-frontend/pods/profile/transport/route`
```

I also tried variations of the import, but without success.

am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into your Ember Inspector, you can click on container and see the names of all the templates ember knows about. I did a quick test with a new ember-cli app, and it looks like in your case it will be:

```
components/modal-picker
```

so your code should change to:

```
showPicker: (name, model)->
  @render('components/modal-picker'
    outlet: 'modal-picker'
```

**EDIT 1:**

you want some template to render into the modal, so you'll want to use the modal-picker component, but like so:

**routes/application.js**

```
showPicker: (templateName, model)->
  @render(templateName
    into: 'application'
    outlet: 'modal-picker'
    model: model
```

**templates/template-with-modal-button**:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" {{action 'showPicker' 'some-cool-template' model}}><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Car</button>
```

Then, when you call the modal-picker in the template, the modal-picker template is where your modal code goes, probably something like:

**components/modal-link/template**

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{yield}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**templates/some-cool-template**

```
{{#modal-picker}}
  <p> some text, probably some form elements too</p>
{{/modal-picker}}
```

EDIT 2: [this is a good reference](http://ember.guru/2014/master-your-modals-in-ember-js) for modals in ember (though it is incomplete)

Comment: After changing to your suggestion I now get the following error when triggering the **showPicker** action: ```Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You called yield in a template that was not a layout```

Comment: Yeah I ran into that too. What you can do is either: A) not call yield in your modal template (probably not what you want), or B) change your code so that the template you pass in is not your modal template (since that will get loaded automatically when you use the modal-picker component)